# npm link does not work (windows); using git and node.js for lexandra/Aardwolf.git

Tags: windows, node.js, npm

I'm following the setup instructions for this mobile javascript debugger [here](https://github.com/lexandera/Aardwolf).  FYI, I'm using Windows XP SP2 32-bit.  Please understand I am new to using git, node.js, and npm.

Now, I'm stuck on this step

```
Download the required libraries by running "npm link" in the checked-out directory
```

The link [here](http://npmjs.org/doc/README.html) helped me a great deal with breaking down the steps from the first link.  I deduced that the directory, Aardwolf, was 'checked-out' when I issued the git clone command.  I tried running npm link on the directory, from within the Git Bash window, and this is what I got;

```
npm.cmd link ../../Aardwolf
./npm.cmd: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
./npm.cmd: line 7: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Then, I reinstalled Git and tried using it through the Windows Command line and this is the result:

```
npm link
npm ERR: Error: npm link not supported on windows
```

And then it gives more errors at particular files, but that's the main one.

So, I tried using npm link and it's supposedly not supported on Windows.  Is there a workaround for this???

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to Windows XP only partially supporting [Symlinks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link), and similarly Windows Vista and 7 requiring admin rights to use Symlinks.

The issue of npm link failing on windows was raised on the npm [github](https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/1845) page.

Answer (score 0):

I tried, in nodejs 0.65 version the link command does not work by saying: not support on windows. 
But using the latest version of nodejs 0.8.1, it works!
oh, mine is windows 7 x64

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try mklink or junction as described here http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/ (and then inform us of your findings!)