# Trouble with cradle on windows

Tags: node.js, couchdb, cradle

I run `npm install -g cradle` and get the output:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cradle
.... lots of more GET's .....
cradle@0.6.3 C:\Users\...\npm\node_modules\cradle
├── vargs@0.1.0
├── request@2.9.153
└── follow@0.7.1
```

Everything seems to work fine.

But when I run my `server.js`

```
var fs = require("fs");
var express = require("express");
var site = express.createServer();
var io = require("socket.io").listen(site);
var cradle = require('cradle');

io.set('log level', 1);

// Determine which dist directory to use
var dir = process.argv.length > 2 && "./dist/" + process.argv[2];

// Use custom JS folder based off debug or release
dir && site.use("/assets/js", express.static(dir + "/js"));
dir && site.use("/assets/css", express.static(dir + "/css"));

// Serve static files
site.use("/app", express.static("./app"));
site.use("/assets", express.static("./assets"));
site.use("/dist", express.static("./dist"));

// Serve favicon.ico
site.use(express.favicon("./favicon.ico"));

// Ensure all routes go home, client side app..
site.get("*", function (req, res) {
    fs.createReadStream("./index.html").pipe(res);
});

// Communication with clients
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('user connected');

    socket.on('testCommunication', function (message, fn) {
        fn(message + ' world');
    });
});

site.listen(8000);
```

, I get the output:

```
    info  - socket.io started

node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
    Error: Cannot find module 'cradle'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:334:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
    at require (module.js:368:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\node\opensthlm\server.js:6:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:432:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:450:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:351:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:470:10)
```

The module resides in the same directory as socket.io, express etc that I have no trouble loading.
I have been staring at this error for an hour. I've used cradle on mac before and it worked like a charm, now I'm on windows, could that have something to do with it? Otherwise I'm clueless. Any ideas?

Comment: Not that proficient with node, and have had weird seeming issues with require myself. This may seem small, but the single ' and double " difference with the cradle require isn't the problem, is it?

Comment: I've updated my post to include the full server.js 
I'm not really making a couchDB-request as far as I can tell, the server just cannot find the module, am I wrong in this assumption?

Comment: do remember to mark the answer if it has helped you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also running node on Windows. I copied your code and then I issued the following commands.

- npm install express
- npm install socket.io
- npm install cradle
- node server.js

Everything seems to run fine.
After the cradle install I got

```
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/cradle
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/cradle
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/follow
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/vargs/0.1.0
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/vargs/0.1.0
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/vargs/-/vargs-0.1.0.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/follow
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/vargs/-/vargs-0.1.0.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/request
cradle@0.6.3 ./node_modules/cradle
├── vargs@0.1.0
├── request@2.9.153
└── follow@0.7.2
```

Notice that I did not use the global install option of npm1.x

Kristof

P.S. The root cause seems to be npm link not working on windows. See

- http://groups.google.com/group/npm-/browse_thread/thread/13f20c6845bc90d6?pli=1
- [npm link does not work (windows); using git and node.js for lexandra/Aardwolf.git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173197/npm-link-does-not-work-windows-using-git-and-node-js-for-lexandra-aardwolf-gi)
- https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/1845

Answer (score 0):

install cradle using :

```
npm install cradle
```

do not use -g switch. That did the trick for me.

BTW: I ran command prompt in admin mode.

http://prazjain.wordpress.com/2012/04/24/node-js-error-error-cannot-find-module-xyz/